# IQueryable. The specifics of the comparison operators (== and >=)

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

While working with Linq2DB faced an unpleasant problem - comparison operators `==` and `>=` are not working correctly. Although the operator `<=` works fine.
At first I decided that the problem is in Linq To SQLite, so have created issue on [github](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/378). But then I found out that a same problem in LinqToSql.
I'll repeat the code from there to demonstrate the problem:

Classes:

```
    [Table(Name = "Records")]
    public class Record
    {
        [Column(Name = "Date"), NotNull]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "Value"), NotNull]
        public decimal Value { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} - {1}", Date, Value);
        }
    }

    public class Db : LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection
    {
        public Db() : base("MyDatabase") { }

        public ITable<Record> Records { get { return GetTable<Record>(); } }
    }
```

Test query:

```
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact("14.01.2016", "dd.MM.yyyy", null);
    Console.WriteLine("All:");
    using (var db = new Db())
    {
        db.Records
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("With Date >= {0}", date);
    using (var db = new Db())
    {
        db.Records
            .Where(x => x.Date >= date)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
```

Print:

```
All:
01.01.2016 0:00:00 - 67
02.01.2016 0:00:00 - 75
03.01.2016 0:00:00 - 70
04.01.2016 0:00:00 - 81
07.01.2016 0:00:00 - 8
08.01.2016 0:00:00 - 27
11.01.2016 0:00:00 - 30
12.01.2016 0:00:00 - 68
13.01.2016 0:00:00 - 20
14.01.2016 0:00:00 - 34
15.01.2016 0:00:00 - 1
16.01.2016 0:00:00 - 66
With Date >= 14.01.2016 0:00:00
15.01.2016 0:00:00 - 1
16.01.2016 0:00:00 - 66
```

Comparison on IEnumerable solves the problem:

```
    Console.WriteLine("With Date >= {0}", date);
    using (var db = new Db())
    {
        db.Records
            .ToArray()
            .Where(x => x.Date >= date)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
```

Print:

```
...
With Date >= 14.01.2016 0:00:00
14.01.2016 0:00:00 - 34
15.01.2016 0:00:00 - 1
16.01.2016 0:00:00 - 66
```

So the question is: what is the reason of such behavior?

**Edit:**

If the problem is with the time difference, then why comparison in SQLite Manager is correct?

[image]

Comment: Is your db using a different timezone than the machine qquerying it?

Comment: @Servy, thank you, maybe. How can I check it ?

Comment: You could just write a query to get the current time, and compare it to your watch.

Comment: @Servy, I'm not sure I understand you correctly. I don't know how to do query with Linq To Db. But if I get the date from db using SQLite Manager, it is different from my local time to 4 hours.

Comment: Then your db is indeed set to a different timezone than your machine.  You'll need to compensate if you want them to behave the same.

Comment: Do you see the difference between SQLiteManager YYYY-MM-DD and your DD.MM.YYYY? That's surely locale specific, so you have a timezone+locale issue. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Your database is set to a different timezone than your local machine, which is why the computations are different when performed by the database than when performed on your machine.

Comment: Thank you. Where can I learn more about it? After all, the dates for which the comparison is different from the current one. Or it does not matter?

Comment: @FoggyFinder You can use Google to learn more about what timezones are.  There is lots of resources out there on the subject.  SQLite Manager is undoubtably considering the date to be in the timezone of the database its connecting to, it's not considering it to be in the local time of the machine running it.

Comment: You are engaged in substitution of concepts - it is not good. You say that the SQLite Manager it takes into account different time zones. Okay, then what should I consider when requesting?

Comment: @FoggyFinder I didn't say that at all.  I just said that SQLite Manager is treating that date as being in the local time of the database, and the C# program is considering it to be in the local time of the C# machine.

Comment: Okay, but you have not answered any of my question.

Comment: I've answered all of your questions.  It's rather rude of you to insult me in response to doing so.  It doesn't exactly make me want to continue helping you if you're going to be so rude.

Answer (score 1):

There is a short answer and a long answer. As it was pointed out, the DB is using a different timezone. This is somewhat SQLite specific, the timezone in SQLite is set to UTC. So, a simple solution might be something along these lines:

```
var dt = new System.DateTime(2016,7,30).AddHours(-9.0).ToLocalTime();
dt.Dump();
Table2
    .Where(r => r.Date1 == dt).Dump();
```

You will get back:
`100 2016-07-30` (where 100 is just the id). So the equality is working as intended. 
Please note that type of date yyyy-MM-dd. In fact if you are lucky you can get away with
`var dt= new DateTime(2016, 7, 30,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Local);`
 Or `DateTimeKind.UTC`.

You might try these two different dates and see the result (this is a one liner in LinqPad btw....):

```
using (var db = new Db())
            {
                Record newdt = new Record { Value = 1000, Date = new System.DateTime(2016, 8, 30, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local) };
                Record newdtUtc = new Record { Value = 2000, Date = new System.DateTime(2016, 8, 30, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) };
                db.Insert(newdt);
                db.Insert(newdtUtc);
```

so now we have August 30 in Local and in UTC in the DB. Now let's extract them:

```
    var dateLoc = new DateTime(2016, 8,30 ,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Local);
    var dateUTC = new DateTime(2016, 8, 30, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    var date = dateLoc.ToString() + " Or " + dateUTC.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("With Date == {0}", date);

    using (var db = new Db())
    {
        db.Records
             .Where(x => x.Date  == dateLoc || x.Date == dateUTC) 
             .ToList()
             .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
```

And voila (plz note that the .ToString() returns both UTC and Local with 00:00:00):

[image: ConsoleApplication1.exe]

Now the longer answer:

The fact that SQLite's timezone is set to UTC is the smaller problem. The bigger one is that SQLite really doesn't have the concept of a Datetime. It stores dates as text or floats, and you can assign whatever type you want to the data column. And indeed SQLite has a bunch of date conversion functions inside, no doubt SQLiteManager is translating back and forth under the hood. So depending on what you use to load the dates and what you use to extract the dates, you might get a different result (depending on what kind of translation is implemented. In fact depending on some date types LinqToDB will silently not do anything but LinqToSql will spectacularly fail by complaining about unknown date formats.

So it is entirely possible that even with the above the adjustments you won't be able to match on the date. In that case you will have to examine your locale. And set the short time date to YYYY-MM-DD and the long time format to HH:MM:SS. And then load the dates and extract them and see if you get a match. At that point you will have to decide if you maybe one to store dates as floats or text in SQLite.

Comment: Is there a value in storing date strings in "datetime" at all, if one does not care about UTC conversion of input?

Comment: Yes. If you are using some sort of ORM, it will map it back to a datetime　when u get it out of the db. Also sqlite is frequently used as a mocking tool before implementing tbe final and larger design in a bigger db.